# Finding functional extremals

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization, calculus-of-variations

So my problem is as follows: find the extremals of the functional
$$I[x_1(t), x_2(t)]=\int_{0.5}^1(\dot{x}_1^{2}-2x_{1}\dot{x}_2t)dt,$$
given: 
$$x_1(0.5)=2, \ \ \ \  x_2(0.5)=15, \  \ \ \  x_1(1)=1, \ \ \ \  x_{2}(1)=1.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far? What about using the Euler-Lagrange equation? The first term inside the integral is $\dot{x}_1^2$ or $\dot{x}_2^2$?

Comment: @rafa11111 Corrected the integral. I tried using Euler-Lagrange equation, but I go stuck and don't know how to interprete the "dt" at the end of integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lagrange function is
$$L(x_1,x_2,\dot{x_1}, \dot{x_2},t)=\dot{x_1}^2-2x_1\dot{x_2}$$
And the Euler-Lagrange equations are
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_1}}\right)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_2}}\right)=0$$
Which will give you a system of differential equations. And your second Euler-Lagrange equation will be a bit easier, because the Lagrange function is independent of $x_2$:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_2}}\right)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_2}}=\text{constant}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86687/discussion-on-answer-by-botond-finding-functional-extremals).